# Show full month name in Daterange picker

Tags: javascript, momentjs, daterangepicker

How can I change the month name of daterange picker to full month name?
Currently it displays only 3 chars of the month.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAmv0.png]

I want to show full month names. I used https://www.daterangepicker.com/ as my template.

Comment: Please post your code, not a screenshot

Comment: Uhhhhh, which ui library are you using? The [jQuery daterangepicker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/) or the [Microsoft monthcalendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar?view=netframework-4.8)? You tagged both...

Comment: I am using this datarange picker https://www.daterangepicker.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set `options.locale.monthNames` to `moment.months()`. The months default to `moment.monthsShort()`.

Here are the default locale settings:

```js
this.locale = {
  direction: 'ltr',
  format: moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L'),
  separator: ' - ',
  applyLabel: 'Apply',
  cancelLabel: 'Cancel',
  weekLabel: 'W',
  customRangeLabel: 'Custom Range',
  daysOfWeek: moment.weekdaysMin(),
  monthNames: moment.monthsShort(),
  firstDay: moment.localeData().firstDayOfWeek()
};
```

```js
// Based on: https://www.daterangepicker.com/#example1
$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left',
    locale: {
      monthNames: moment.months()
    }
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2018 - 01/15/2018" />
```